# Retrieve Pyramid's auth_tkt via HTTP response headers on mobile client

Tags: rest, authentication, httpresponse, pyramid

I am writing a mobile iOS application, which communicates with a Pyramid app on the backend. I am currently using Pyramid's built-in AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy.

I've met some speed bumps while attempting to authenticate via a mobile client (iPhone). For starters, how would I send and retrieve the auth_tkt cookie that is set by Pyramid.

I understand how this works with a web browser, but, if I want to send this "auth_tkt cookie" in the HTTP response, how can I accomplish this? How do I actually get the auth_tkt secret string. For example, what if I'd like to return it in the JSON body or a custom header of my choosing rather than as the cookie set by Pyramid's remember function?

Secondly, in future requests sent by the client what header do I set with the auth_tkt secret string so that Pyramid recognizes it and appropriately authenticates the client?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pyramid Helper Classes [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html#helper-classes), it looks like you can create your own auth_tkt and access it as well.  Example from docs:

```
token = AuthTicket('sharedsecret', 'username',
os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR'], tokens=['admin'])
val = token.cookie_value()
```

Comment: I don't particularly want just to create my own. I'd like the leverage the cookies "auth_tkt"'s created by pyramid.security.remember() but I don't see how this is possible. I was hoping there's an alternative to creating my own custom authentication policy, having to implement AuthTktCookieHelper and AuthTicket classes as well, just so that the cookies can be returned. Ideally I was hoping for a way to access these cookies from the response headers so that I can return them in the json body. Is this not possible? Is this bad practice?

Comment: I can't vouch for the best practice, but I would say it is possible.  I use AngularJS with Pyramid in the backend.  I don't do anything special in Pyramid.  Here are the significant lines: `headers = remember(request, str(user._id))`, `request.response.headerlist.extend(headers)`.  To authorise users in my Angular app, I access the Pyramid authticket on the client side.  Every request resends the cookie in the header so that the Pyramid app can ensure a user should still be logged in.  I guess you could send the authticket string back in the json body, but its not the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

The headers is a webob ResponseHeaders object, it derives from webob multidict. You can get it value by using this:

```
set_cookie = request.response.headers['set-cookie']
```

You can refer this link: [webob multidict](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/api/multidict.html)